# how to make dropdown drop up through Material ui select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material ui select
how to make a dropdown so that it falls out to the top, now it always falls down I want to make it go up through api or something else but it doesn’t work

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-zhukovsky-0ovd2q?file=/demo.tsx
[image]

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setAge(event.target.value as string);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        position: "relative",
        top: "200px",
        minWidth: 10
      }}
    >
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MenuProps` like this:

```
       <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
          MenuProps={{
            anchorOrigin: {
              vertical: "top",
              horizontal: "right"
            },
            transformOrigin: {
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "right"
            },
            sx: { mt: "-15px", ml: "5px"  }
          }}
        >
```

Comment: thanks, where did you find this property, I can't find it in the documentation(  anchorOrigin and transformOrigin

Comment: Hey! You can find `MenuProps` here https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/, but the other here https://mui.com/material-ui/api/popover/ it is weird because they do not appear in the Select props