# React Material UI Select Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

[image]

While clicking on the dropdown it opens above the dropdown it should be down but I cannot fix the style.

Please help me on that

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select, {SelectChangeEvent} from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function DropDownSelect({data}: any) {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{Width: 30}}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Select</InputLabel>
        <Select
          sx={{
            width: '100%',
            height: 50,
            borderColor: 'red',
          }}
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="age"
          onChange={handleChange}>
          {data.map((option: any) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Help me with style part not able to fix the design issue

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74530540/11095009

Comment: Not Working i tried

Comment: If you want, you can add some code so I can help

Comment: export default function DropDownSelect({data}: any) {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{Width: 30}}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Select</InputLabel>
        <Select
          sx={{
            width: '100%',
            height: 50,
            borderColor: 'red',
          }}

Comment: labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="age"
          onChange={handleChange}>
          {data.map((option: any) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}

Comment: code is long so sent in two parts

Comment: You should not add the code here but in the question itself

Comment: I've tried the code but it doesn't happen what you say. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-oh3ixd?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: i have 100s of data that's why I think dropdown is not working properly